# A combination problem with repeated number

Tags: combinatorics

We know about the combination problems. However, if we say the numbers are $1,1,2,3,4,5$, then how many unique numbers with $6$ digits can be written with these numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you put the 1's

6C2

then you multiply by 4! to permutate the others

another way to do it is:

do 6! and then divide by 2! in this case, what youre doing is: permutate every number and then dividing by the permutations of the repeated number

for instance, if you had 1 1 2 2 3 4 you'd do 6! divided by (2! * 2 ! )

(i do not know who voted -1 ...... this answer is indeed correct)

Comment: you can also do 6! and then divide by 2!
in  this case, what youre doing is: permutate every number and then dividing by the permutations of the repeated number

for instance, if you had 1 1 2 2 3 4
you'd do 6! divided by (2! * 2 ! )

Comment: Write your answer in detail if possible.

Comment: what do you mean ? was I not clear ?